# Google app engine or amazon web services

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

I am a newbie to us cloud hosting. I want to know which is better to start with, either Google app engine or Amazon web service.

My questions are:

1. My application is based on java, Database is MySQL. Do they support this?
2. What are the free offers from both of them and which one is better to start?
3. How easy would it be to migrate from one platform to another?
4. Any good link for getting started with these service as I am a novice here.

Additionally, I'd appreciate some good links for getting started with these services as I am a novice here, and a high level view on how this works.

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo Its funny how you say posts like this are not constructive, I often find the posts that you close are some of the most constructive, people are looking to answer questions like this. just look at the views 13506

Comment: I was hoping to get the collective advice of the SO community on this question. This is definitely related to coding. I want to know how to best deploy my code on the web. I guess I'll take my inquiry to even further corners of the web——unfortunately.

Comment: They love closing all the most interesting questions.. "Your question must have a binary answer!"

Comment: Yes definitely this is a good question. I did't see it as not constructive as many of us are begging a good answer to the similar question. I would suggest SO to do a closing by means of user voting or collective advice of the SO community. Not by some perceptions.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

**Update**: The answer is no longer up to date. Since Google's Cloud SQL is no longer in BETA that means that both AWS and GAE support java apps written to use a MySQL database and that migrating is no longer that difficult. The overall idea is that both cloud providers tend to get to a point where they offer "everything": Google launched [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine) while Amazon is working on [Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). However, Amazon's IaaS services are more mature than Google's while Google's PaaS services are more mature than Amazon's. It all boils down to whether you want IaaS or PaaS.

---

There is a key difference between AWS and Google App Engine: AWS is infrastructure as a service (IaaS) whereas GAE is platform as a service (PaaS). What this means is that with AWS you still need to administer your own servers (ec2 instances, db instances, load balancers and so on) => some sysadmin work required. With GAE you just need to code your app and deploy it to the google cloud without caring on what servers or on how many servers it runs. Google does all the sysadmin work for you.

Both use a pay-for-use model.

Answers for each question:

1. Supported by AWS. For GAE you need to use their own data storage (it's called big table). You can use JPA for accessing big table data, but there are a lot of restrictions (like you can't do table joins for example). GAE has [support for relational databases](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide) but it seems to be in beta.
2. They both have some free plan: [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/)
3. Difficult. As I said at point 1, gae uses a proprietary NoSql data storage. If you want to switch to a relational model you will need to redesign your models.
4. Read their tutorials: [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html), [GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction).

**Note**: AWS also has support for PaaS through [elastic beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) , but that's still in BETA

Comment: A1 is incorrect since App Engine also supports mysql. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide

Comment: @Takashi Thanks. I wasn't aware of this new feature. Edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: +1 for the differences between Google's PaaS and Amazon's IaaS, in my opinion is one of the key differences between them.

Comment: you might add pricing into consideration. Google is in the catch-up mode hence it's pricing is generally better (they claim, upto 40%). that might depend on the actual usecase.
[Amazon AWS Price calulator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) vs [Google Cloud Price Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)